# how to avoid division calculation outputting a remainder number ie 4.333333 with the code i am using

Tags: javascript, division

I am looking for when the division calc is run it wont output an answer which will have remainders.

```js
function runGame(gameType) {

    // Generate two random numbers between 1 and 25
    // Math.floor rounds down to the whole number
    // Math.random generates random numbers

    document.getElementById("answer-box").value = "";
    document.getElementById("answer-box").focus();

    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1;
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1;

    if (gameType === "addition") {
        displayAdditionQuestion(num1, num2);
    } else if (gameType === "multiply") {
        displayMultiplyQuestion(num1, num2);
    } else if (gameType === "subtract") {
        displaySubtractQuestion(num1, num2);
    } else {
        alert(`Unknown game type ${gameType}`);
        throw `Unknown game type ${gameType}, aborting!`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Math.round(number)` to round it to the nearest integer.

Alternatively if you don't care about the remainder at all you can use `const answer = division >> 0` to bitshift it to 0 and just throw away the remainder.